# Windows Phone 8.1 (runtime) additional data in OnMapTapped event

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, bing-maps

I am trying to create a Windows Phone 8.1 (Runtime) app that has a Map Control on it.  I would like to attach additional data to the OnMappedTapped event or a way to grab an assigned Location ID when someone clicks on the MapIcon.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. If you want to do something when someone clicks on a MapIcon (pushpin), then add a tap to the map and then do a search for elements that intersect the touch point using the Map.FindMapElementsAtOffset method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.maps.mapcontrol.findmapelementsatoffset.aspx

or the Map.FindSubElementsForTouchTargeting method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.findsubelementsfortouchtargeting.aspx

When it comes to storing or associating data to a pushpin, I like to store my data in the standard Tag property as that's something I've been doing for a while with WPF and Silverlight. You will notice that the MapIcon/MapElement classes do not have a Tag property, however they are DependancyObjects which meanswe can easily add custom properties to these classes. Here is a simple extension I often use in my WP apps to add a Tag property to these classes.

```
public static class MapElementExt
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TagProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Tag", typeof(object), typeof(MapElement), new PropertyMetadata(null));
}
```

You can then set this value like this:

```
pushpin.SetValue(MapElementExt.TagProperty, MyPinData);
```

Personally, when it comes to pushpins I normally don't mess with the MapIcon/MapElement classes and just create a UIElement for my pushpin. By doing this I can easily have a lot more control over creating my pushpin and can also easily add Tap events. You can specify the location for a UIElement like this:

```
MapControl.SetLocation(pushpin, MyGeopoint);
```

And then add the pushpin to the Map.Children property.

If you want to get the coordinates for a randomly selected point on a map through a touch event you can take the pixel coordinates from the tap event and pass them through the Map.GetLocationFromOffset method. For example:

```
MyMap.Tapped += (s, e) =>
{
    Geopoint loc;
    MyMap.GetLocationFromOffset(e.GetPosition(MyMap), out loc);
};
```

Comment: Once I add pushpin.SetValue(MapElementExt.TagProperty, MyPinData); how do I retrieve the tag value in the OnMapTapped event?  Or if the UIElement is a better option do you have a link to sample?  Thx.

Comment: Try something like:

var val = (sender as UIElement).GetValue(MapElementExt.TagProperty);
if(val != null)
var MyPinData = val as MyObjectType;

Comment: I must be missing something cause its not working.   mapIcon.SetValue(MapElementExt.TagProperty, location.LocationId); and then in my map tapped   var val = (sender as UIElement).GetValue(MapElementExt.TagProperty);  but val is null.

Comment: instead of doing (as UIElement) try (as MapElement)

Comment: I did a little more research and ended up going the route of creating a UIElement for my pushpin like you suggested.  Would you be willing to take a look at my code to make sure it is right? Thx.